# emberjs get all form fields / values at once

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

When creating new form fields in ember.js, it seems as though there's a multi-step process.  For example, I create the form fields:

```
{{input value=email type="email" placeholder="Email" required="required"}}
{{input value=password type="password" placeholder="Password" required="required"}}
```

then in my controller I have this:

```
App.AccountController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    email: null,
    password: null,
    actions: {
      login: function() {
        var data = this.getProperties("email", "password");

            console.log(data);
      }
    }
});
```

As you can see, email and password are defined as null at the top, and then again in the data var to get the 'values' when the user fills in the fields.

Is there a way around this, where I can simply say... take all Values in the form field, assign to null and then get all form field values in one line?  Similar maybe to serialize form in jQuery?

Comment: For clarification, are you looking for a way to get all of the form values without having to explicitly list out each field?

Comment: Yes correct, it seems that after I've created the form field, I shouldn't have to define it as null, and then again to get the property.

Comment: You can even get away without specifying controller, you can set in route model as 'currentUser', the in login action (also in route) just pass the this.get('currentUser'), which will contain every form value

Comment: @licancabur can you provide a quick example? (in code)

Comment: looks like this (in coffeescript): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d3814bd45fc1a6fc56a . Its in my current project, I'm not providing the values as needed. I don't know if this is a recommended way if you're using Ember-data.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you're going to need repetition. The long answer is that you *could* avoid repetition, but at a cost that isn't worth it.

First of all, you don't have to define the fields in your controller. These two lines could be delete entirely:

```
email: null,
password: null,
```

However, I would highly recommend keeping them for documentation purposes. (They're unnecessary though.)

Secondly, you have to realize that Ember has no concept of a 'form'. You haven't specified any forms, just two input boxes. If you wanted to, you could probably build a form component to do exactly what you want, but I would only suggest that if you were building a *lot* of forms. In the end, you're going to have a fair amount of repetition.

That being said, I think the way you're written your code is perfect. Don't look for the shortest way to write code; look for the most readable way to write code. The code you currently have is the most readable version of that code (in my opinion).

---

EDIT: I didn't notice an `ObjectController` was being used. That forwards get and set calls to the content of the controller if the fields aren't explicitly set on the controller. That means that removing those two lines won't work. However, if you extend from `Controller` instead of `ObjectController` (which is deprecated anyway), it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  When I took out the null, I got this error:  Error: Property set failed: object in path "email" could not be found or was destroyed.

Comment: Ahh, that's probably because you're using an `ObjectController` and not just a plain `Controller`. `ObjectController's are deprecated, you should probably extend from `Controller` instead. That will fix that issue.

Comment: Instead of using `.getProperties` I often bind the inputs to an object which then in the action I can interact with there. This works great with ember data where you can bind the inputs to a model and just call `save()` in the action.

Also consider using a component for your inputs as you can then bind to the errors returned from an object also.